# Merging two images with ImageMagick Convert -combine option Changes Colors

Tags: imagemagick

I am trying to merge two images into one.
One image has a grid: [image: CDC Boys BMI]
and the other image has data points: [image: Data Points]

using the command:

```
convert -combine -verbose -clamp Boys_BMI.png Ipc2eAOT.png new.png
```

I get this information:

```
Boys_BMI.png PNG 1700x2200 1700x2200+0+0 8-bit Palette sRGB 33c 198982B 0.047u 0:00.040
Ipc2eAOT.png PNG 1700x2200 1700x2200+0+0 8-bit TrueColor sRGB 16711B 0.031u 0:00.032
Boys_BMI.png=>new.png PNG 1700x2200 1700x2200+0+0 8-bit sRGB 198982B 2.734u 0:00.328
```

and the resulting image looks like this: [image: Merged Image]

Is there a way for the merged image (new.png) to keep the original colors from the original two images?

Thank you,
Roberto

Answer (score 2, accepted):

-combine is the wrong method to use. It combines channels, not images. What you want to do in Imagemagick is make white into transparent in your points image and then -composite it over the grid image.

Also your syntax is incorrect. You should read the images right after convert and before any operations.

```
convert grid.png \( points.png -transparent white \) -compose over -composite merged.png
```

[image]

Comment: That works really well, thank you.

Something I did not notice until now is that the data points are not in the correct position, the lower-leftmost point should be at the bottom of the chart at the 2 years mark, and the top-rightmost point should be at the top of the chart at 20 years.

Is like the data points got compressed, but both images have the same size...

Comment: No, wait.. The problem is on my side, the generation of the image with only data points is placing the data points on a different coordinates... let me talk to my program.

thank you again.